# Pytorch to Keras code equivalence

Tags: keras, pytorch

Given a below code in PyTorch what would be the Keras equivalent?

```
class Network(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        super(Network, self).__init__()

        # Inputs = 5, Outputs = 3, Hidden = 30
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(5, 30)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(30, 3)

    def forward(self, state):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        outputs = self.fc2(x)
        return outputs
```

Is it this?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=30, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='linear'))
```

or is it this?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=30, input_dim=5, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(units=30, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='linear'))
```

or is it?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=30, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=30, activation='linear'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='linear'))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of them looks correct according to my knowledge. A correct Keras equivalent code would be:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_shape=(5,), activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(3))
```

> model.add(Dense(30, input_shape=(5,), activation='relu'))

Model will take as input arrays of shape (*, 5) and output arrays of shape (*, 30). Instead of `input_shape`, you can use `input_dim` also. `input_dim=5` is equivalent to `input_shape=(5,)`.

> model.add(Dense(3))

After the first layer, you don't need to specify the size of the input anymore. Moreover, if you don't specify anything for activation, no activation will be applied (equivalent to linear activation).

---

Another alternative would be:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=5)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
```

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: 2 dense layers, one with activation `relu` and other is `linear`.

Comment: There is a "hidden input layer" too that doesn't appear in this case. If you count this, they're 3 layers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=input_shape(5,)) 
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu')
model.add(Dense(3))
```

If you are trying to convert Pytorch model to Keras model, you can also try a [Pytorch2Keras](https://github.com/nerox8664/pytorch2keras) converter.

It supports base layers like Conv2d, Linear, Activations, Element-wise operations. So, I've converted ResNet50 with error 1e-6.

Answer (score -1):

```
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=5, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dense(3, activation=None))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.